# How to get table header to change size when content changes

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a table with a table header to keep up with scrolling. When someone clicks on of the content rows it opens a few extra rows. The problem is that the header table doesn't change size to keep up with the content changes. The main goal would be to keep the header always on top and to match the size of the content when a row is clicked.

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="ctrl">
  <table>
    <tr style="background:red;">
      <td>one</td>
      <td>open</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div style="height: 66px; overflow-y: scroll;">
    <table>
      <tbody ng-repeat="item in items"  ng-click="showSubs = !showSubs">
        <tr>
          <td>{{item.text}}</td>
          <td>{{item.text2}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="sub in subItems" ng-show="showSubs">
          <td colspan="2">
            {{sub.text}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mw0cfb8s/)

Comment: Your markup is very specific. I don't even know which way to fix it. Why is the header separate from the main table? You should be able to do this with one table, not two.

Comment: Made it as two because I wasn't sure how to keep the top row always at the top and scroll the body. .